# What is the idiomatic way to assoc several keys/values in a nested map in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, idioms

Imagine you have a map like this:

```
(def person {
  :name {
    :first-name "John"
    :middle-name "Michael"
    :last-name "Smith" }})
```

What is the idiomatic way to change values associated with both :first-name and :last-name in one expression?

(Clarification: Let's say you want to set :first-name to "Bob" and :last-name to "Doe". Let's also say that this map has some other values in it that we want to preserve, so constructing it from scratch is not an option)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Here are a couple of ways.

```
user> (update-in person [:name] assoc :first-name "Bob" :last-name "Doe")
{:name {:middle-name "Michael", :last-name "Doe", :first-name "Bob"}}

user> (update-in person [:name] merge {:first-name "Bob" :last-name "Doe"})
{:name {:middle-name "Michael", :last-name "Doe", :first-name "Bob"}}

user> (update-in person [:name] into {:first-name "Bob" :last-name "Doe"})
{:name {:middle-name "Michael", :last-name "Doe", :first-name "Bob"}}

user> (-> person 
          (assoc-in [:name :first-name] "Bob")
          (assoc-in [:name :last-name]  "Doe"))
{:name {:middle-name "Michael", :last-name "Doe", :first-name "Bob"}}
```

### Edit

`update-in` does recursive `assoc`s on your map.  In this case it's roughly equivalent to:

```
user> (assoc person :name 
             (assoc (:name person) 
                    :first-name "Bob" 
                    :last-name "Doe"))
```

The repetition of keys becomes more and more tedious as you go deeper into a series of nested maps.  `update-in`'s recursion lets you avoid repeating keys (e.g. `:name`) over and over; intermediary results are stored on the stack between recursive calls.  Take a look at the source for [update-in](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/update-in) to see how it's done.

```
user> (def foo {:bar {:baz {:quux 123}}})
#'user/foo

user> (assoc foo :bar 
             (assoc (:bar foo) :baz 
                    (assoc (:baz (:bar foo)) :quux 
                           (inc (:quux (:baz (:bar foo)))))))
{:bar {:baz {:quux 124}}}

user> (update-in foo [:bar :baz :quux] inc)
{:bar {:baz {:quux 124}}}
```

`assoc` is dynamic (as are `update-in`, `assoc-in`, and most other Clojure functions that operate on Clojure data structures).  If `assoc` onto a map, it returns a map.  If you `assoc` onto a vector, it returns a vector.  Look at the source for [assoc](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/assoc) and take a look in in `RT.java` in the Clojure source for details.

Comment: Thanks! How does the syntax of the first statement work? How does assoc know that it's operating on a map that's passed into it by "update-in"? It looks neat, but how does the compiler not get confused?

Comment: assoc does not care if just gets a map and some args (the pairs) then it does its thing. The map that you get back will be put into the right place by the update-in semantics with then returnes as a hole map.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but I added some edits to expand on the answer, hope that helps a bit.

Comment: Thanks again. I was struggling with the 'assoc :first-name "Bob" :last-name "Doe"' part, trying to figure out how does assoc "know" which map it should put the keys/values into (given that the usual syntax for assoc includes the map variable before the keys/values begin, such as (assoc myMap :first-name "Bob" :last-name "Doe"). I'm going to play with this a bit more.

Comment: It's all about the 'apply' function being used inside 'update-in', as it turns out. I'm all set now, thanks Brian.

Comment: 7 year old question, but still relevant.  I tried the suggested solution, `(update-in person [] assoc :first-name "Bob" :last-name "Doe")`, where `:first-name` and `:last-name` were supposed to be at the top level, not nested under `:name`, but the new key-value pairs came in under top-level key `nil`.  I'd like to be able to `swap!` multiple values at arbitrary `assoc-in` locations, including at the top level, but I couldn't figure out how to do that with exactly one `swap` call.

Comment: I did this: `(defn multi-assoc-in [m & kvvp] (reduce #(apply assoc-in %1 %2) m (partition 2 kvvp)))` where kvvp is kevvector-value pairs, same as what you'd pass into assoc-in.  Now I can do `(swap! myatom multi-assoc-in [:a :b] "whatever" [:c :d :e] "blabla")`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if my case is quite the same but I had list of changes to apply:

```
(def updates [[[:name :first-name] "Bob"] 
              [[:name :last-name] "Doe"]])
```

In that case you can reduce over that list with assoc-in like this:

```
(reduce #(assoc-in %1 (first %2) (second %2)) person updates)
```